# Save troublesome webpage and import back into Python

Tags: python, html, python-requests, lxml, save-as

I am trying to extract some information from a variety of pages and struggling a bit.  This shows my challenge:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = "https://www.soccer24.com/match/C4RB2hO0/#match-summary"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

If you copy the output into Notepad, you cannot find the value "9.20" anywhere in the output (the Team A odds in the bottom right of the webpage).  However, if you open the webpage, do a Save-As and then import it back into Python like this, you can locate and extract the 9.20 value:

```
with open(r'HUL 1-7 TOT _ Hull - Tottenham _ Match Summary.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)

output = tree.xpath('//*[@id="default-odds"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span[2]/span/text()')  #the xpath for the TeamA odds or the 9.20 value
output # ['9.20']
```

Not sure why this work-around works but that is above me.  So what I would like to do is save a webpage to my local drive and open it in Python, as above and carry on from there. But how do I replicate the Save-As in Python?  This does not work:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read().decode('utf-8')
f = open('HUL 1-7 TOT _ Hull - Tottenham _ Match Summary.html', 'w')
f.write(webContent)
f.flush()
f.close()
```

It gives me a webpage but it is a fraction of the original page...?

Comment: It's probably generated by `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pedro Lobito said. Page content is generated by `javascript`. For this reason you need a module which can run JavaScript. I will choose `requests_html` or `selenium`.

Requests_html

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://www.soccer24.com/match/C4RB2hO0/#match-summary"

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render()
result = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="default-odds"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span[2]/span/text()')
print(result)
#['9.20']
```

Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.soccer24.com/match/C4RB2hO0/#match-summary"
dr = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    dr.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(dr.page_source)
    ''' use it when browser closes before loading succeeds
    # https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
    WebDriverWait(dr, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
    '''
    output = tree.xpath('//*[@id="default-odds"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span[2]/span/text()')  #the xpath for the TeamA odds or the 9.20 value
    print(output)

except Exception as e:
    raise e

finally:
    dr.close()
#['9.20']
```

Comment: Appreciated! I need to get this working in Google Colab and am getting an error (Browser closed unexpectedly) but I will open another question for this.